# VHDL SLA operator

Tags: fpga, vhdl

Maybe it is really easy question but I spent two hours looking for solution and information in the internet and still I can't push it to work.

I need to do arithmetic left shift operation. I used standard SLA operator.

ModelSim during compilation shows an error:

> Blockquote
>   ** Error: (vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator 'sla'.
>   ** Error: Bad right hand side (infix expression) in variable assignment.

My code

```
constant Vlsb : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0) := x"00002710CB29";
i_data      : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

.

```
process(i_clk) is 
    variable data : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
begin 
    if(i_rst_asyn = '0') then
        data := (others => '0');
    else
        if(rising_edge(i_clk)) then
            if(i_rst_syn = '1') then
                data := (others => '0');
            else
                data(15 downto 0) := i_data;
                data := data sla 31; -- ERROR LINE
                data := std_logic_vector(signed(data) / signed(Vlsb));              
            end if;
        end if;
    end if; 
    o_data <= data;
end process;
```

Could sombody tell me what I am doing wrong, please.

Add- I am using std_logic_1164 and numeric_std library in this module.

Comment: There is a good answer on this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035788/4090959. Note that the 'Update' is important.

Comment: Simply declare your variable of a type for which there is a declaration of `sla`; alternatively, nothing stops you writing your own `sla` for the type you have chosen.

Answer (score -2):

To use the operators `sla` or `sll` , etc ... you need to use the `bit_vector` type and not the `std_logic_vector` one.

That's why I don't advise anyone to use these kind of shift operators but rather instantiate a for loop like the following:

```
FOR i IN 0 TO N - 1 LOOP
    data := data(14 DOWNTO 0) & data(0);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: What exactly does the loop do in this example?

Comment: It shifts `data` from N bits to the left in one clock cycle (and pad with '1'). That's what @e2p is looking for I guess

Comment: You mean it's a way of obfuscating `data := data(15-n downto 0) & (n-1 downto 0 => '1');`? Also, where does padding with '1' come from?

Comment: why '1'? , arithmetic left shifting put '0' on empty position

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see what you mean and indeed it works fine. Though I proposed ONE solution , even if there could be many others. And btw @e2p `sla` pads with '1' whereas `sll` pads with '0'.

Comment: Regarding the padding, I think you are confusing `sla` with sign extension in `sra` on negative numbers.

Comment: Ok, I checked and basically `sla` just pads with lsb. My bad.